# How to multiply one pandas dataframe by another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have one data frame of shape `(1, 78)` that consists of beta coefficients for another data frame that is of shape `(250,000, 78)` which are the variables.  The column names from both data frames match each other.  How can I efficiently multiply each row of the larger data frame by the coefficients in the first data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(1, 78)))
df1 = df1/100

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(10, 78)))
df2
```

Essentially, the end product should be a dataframe of `(10, 78)` with df2 having each column multiplied by the corresponding column in df1.

Comment: are you looking for :`pd.DataFrame(np.multiply(df2.values,np.resize(df1.values,df2.shape)))` ?

Comment: yep, that's it. If you put that in an answer I'll check it as a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `np.multiply` and `np.resize`:

```
final=pd.DataFrame(np.multiply(df2.values,np.resize(df1.values,df2.shape)))
print(final.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the multiplication you want:

```
df1.values * df2
```